# Is creating an array and an array list the same thing in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is creating an **array** and creating an **arraylist** the same thing in Java? I hear many different stories with regard to this so if you could point me into the right direction it would much appreciated :)

Comment: Enlighten us with some of those stories too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is a primitive structure. It is sequential memory and allocated by the JVM.

An arraylist uses an array behind it, but you don't have direct access to it. It can "grow" while a regular array cannot.

Basically, an arraylist starts (by default) with an array of length 10 behind it, and a count of 0. So imagine you had

```
ArrayList<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

behind this is an array like this

```
count = 0
array = [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
```

When you go `myInts.add(5);` it does this

```
count = 1
array = [ 5, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
```

If you added more you could get this

```
count = 10
array = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 8, 3, 0, -1 ]
```

And if you added one more (which would push it beyond its capacity) it would make a new array to support it

```
count = 11
array = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 8, 3, 0, -1, 9, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
```

You can change the size of the backing array if you want to. for example:

```
myInts.trimToSize();

count = 11 // hasn't changed
array = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 8, 3, 0, -1, 9]

myInts.ensureCapacity(15);

count = 11 // hasn't changed
array = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 8, 3, 0, -1, 9, null, null, null, null,]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of primitive types while ArrayList doesn't support the primitive types.

You can save some memory if you use Array instead of ArrayList, but will not have the extra features provided by the Java Collection Framework.

Comment: Thought you can use the wrapper classes if you want primitives in an arraylist.

Comment: Wrapper classes are not primitives?

Comment: My point was just that if you were like "I need to use ints", you can still do it using a List and the Integer wrapper class. I don't think they are considered primitives. Only those non-objects and String.

Comment: Yes I got your point. Long time ago when I was just starting and had never heard of Autoboxing, I used to think that I was adding primitive to a List.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, an array can't grow where as an `ArrayList` can. You can even shrink or clear an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

No, these are not the same thing.

Support for real arrays is part of the Java language and the Java Virtual Machine. There are specific instructions in the JVM instruction set to work with arrays.

An `ArrayList` is just a class that's part of the core Java libraries. Internally, it stores elements in a Java array. Compare it to other list implementations like `LinkedList`.

In practice, a `List` implementation like `ArrayList` offers more features than an array. For example, an `ArrayList` can have a varying size, and will re-allocate the underlying array if more space is needed.